# Cannot visualize my data using Switch node

Tags: node-red

I am trying to visualize historical data in Node Red. For that purpose i am using switch node to fliter years but I cannot see my filtered data in the dashboard. Just displaying only the Gauge chart without data.
Can anyone help me to get recovered from this issu??

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here for anybody to be able to help properly. You need to show us what you've configured and what output you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put debug point to check error

[image]

then check what is your data

[image]

then you have to pass correct json object key Value

[image]